# mongodb match all conditions with a single array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of tests like this,

```
{

    "tests" : [

        {
            "testId" : "1",
            "details" : {
                "status" : "Completed"
            }
        },
        {
            "testId" : "2",
            "details" : {
                "status" : "InProgress"
            }
        },
        {
            "testId" : "3",
            "details" : {
                "status" : "Completed"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to search for complete tests with id as 1 or 2.
So I wrote a match query like this

```
{
  $match : { $and : [ { "tests.testId" : { $in : [1, 2] } }
                    ,{ "tests.details.status" : "Completed" }
                   ] 
          } 
}
```

The problem with this query is it fetches all documents with Ids as 1 or 2 even though the status is not Completed. For example the above query fetches these two documents

```
        {
            "testId" : "1",
            "details" : {
                "status" : "Completed"
            }
        },
        {
            "testId" : "2",
            "details" : {
                "status" : "InProgress"
            }
        },
```

What I need is to the query to search for a parituclat array element for both the condition.

I also tried with `$elemMatch`. It still doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` pipeline with `$filter` to return the matched array elements only

try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { // to filter the documents
      $and: [
        {
          "tests.testId": { $in: ["1", "2"] }
        },
        {
          "tests.details.status": "Completed"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // then use this $project stage to use the $filter operator in it
      tests: {
        $filter: { // this is to filter the tests array
          input: "$tests",
          as: "test",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$test.testId", ["1", "2"] 
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$test.details.status",
                  "Completed"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ekHhHiF3oMj)

hope it helps

> Note, If testId is of type ObjectId, then you have to use ObjectIds not strings in the aggregate pipeline

Comment: Thanks. Do I need the initial `$match`. With this logic it should work without it as well. isn't it? Just the `$project` block should work. let me know your thoughts

Comment: It will work in this case without it yes, but in case you have other documents that have that tests array which none of its elements is matching any of your conditions, then we do need it. Also this $match is preferred to make mongodb search by indexes rather than a whole collection scan, hope it’s clear